# Get two strings from one

Tags: lua, love2d

My string is 'ip:port' I want to get the ip into one string and the port to other string.

```
local address = "127.0.0.1:24412"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have found a solution. Another way is:

```
local sIP, sPort = address:match( "([^:]+):(%d+)" )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
local address = string.gmatch(chatString, "[^:]+")
local addressIP = address()
local addressPORT = address()
```

I fount that way, it's work.

---

UPD:
More concise way as suggested by comment:

```
local ip, port = address:match'(.-):(.*)'
```

Comment: `local ip, port = address:match'(.-):(.*)'`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, please add your comment as an answer.